# Twig and pagerfanta get the fieldname and the fieldname.value

Tags: doctrine, twig, symfony, pagerfanta

I'm trying to get the fieldname of a pagerfanta results.

Twig template

```
{% for post in posts %}
{{ dump(post) }} 
{% endfor %}
```

The dump result is:

```
Users {#764 ▼
  -iduser: 11
  -username: "xzvdsfg"
  -password: "SHHHHHH"
  -lastlogin: DateTime {#691 ▶}
  -roles: []
}
```

i want to get the name of each entry without known it to place in a table like this

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>{{ fieldname }}</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <td>{{ fieldname.value }}</td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and get this result

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>username</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <td>xzvdsfg</td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm new at Twig templates 
Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could cast the object to array and iterate over then. You have to create your own [twig filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#filters) to casting your object to array.

```
{% for key, value in post|cast_to_array %}

{% endfor %}
```